# Cache-Control правило для nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Новости имеют следующего типа ссылки: `example.com/news/`. У них Cache-Control настроен правильно = "public".

Но на страницы такого типа:  `example.com/news/?f` and `example.com/news/?e` - не отдается Cache-Control "public".

```
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|json)$ {
expires -1;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
}
```

Сайт на WordPress. Подскажите, как правильно написать правило для такого типа страниц.

Comment: Приведенный location не работает для /news/. Он только для ссылок, который заканчиваются на manifest или appcache или json. У вас еще где-то должен быть Location, который добавляет cache-control "public".

Comment: Как то /news/ работает, может в другом месте правило прописано. Больше вот интересует /?e

Comment: так найдите то правило и покажите, его надо скорректировать

Comment: у нас его нет (. Я про  /?e

Comment: у вас есть в настройках location, который добавляет cache-control "public" в /news/ (раз вы говорите, что У них Cache-Control настроен правильно = "public"). Сам по себе Public появиться не может, значит есть location, где этот public выставляется. логично править этот location

Comment: Все, что есть с public вот: location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|json)$ {
expires -1;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
  location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
   try_files /does_not_exists @php;
  }
}    И ВОТ: location ~* ^.+\.(jp?g|gif|png|ico|bmp|svg)$ {
 access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
        add_header Last-Modified: $date_gmt;
 add_header Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public";
}
Больше нет ничего. Откуда на странице новости тогда берется "public" - я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить

```
location /news/ {
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Но не факт, что будет работать. У вас есть еще где-то подобный location, в котором выставляется public для news (раз вы говорите, что У них Cache-Control настроен правильно = "public"). Как они будут взаимодействовать, предсказать нельзя, не видя полного кода настроек для конкретного сайта.